# Which HTTP web server can I use to debug ruby code using Rubymine 3.0.1?

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

I've being using Mongrel with Rails 2.3.X and Ruby 1.8.7 without problems, but when I switch to Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3, I'm having problems with mongrel to debug.

Webrick is just slow, so, do you know any alternatives? 
Do you know how to fix mongrel to successfully debug rails app using rubymine 3.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get Defaults->Rails changes to affect my different configs that were set to 'Default', but I did have success changing the discrete config ('development') directly. Note: For Mongrel you need to have this in your gemfile:
`gem 'mongrel',  '1.2.0.pre2'`

I'm using RM 3.1.1, Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not using Rails right now but I'll take this into consideration next time:).

Answer (score 2):

RubyMine 3.1 is out now and supports a number of different servers. Under the "Run" menu, select "Edit Configurations" then go to "Defaults->Rails". There you can choose between:

- WEBrick
- lighttpd
- mongrel
- thin
- trinidad
- unicorn
- glassfish