# Is there a way to tell RubyMine to not use webrick?

Tags: ruby, webrick, rubymine, unicorn

When I start my app up in RubyMine I want to be able to use unicorn and my unicorn configs.  Is there any way to tell it not to use webrick but use something else like unicorn or thin?

Comment: Apparently not: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-7219?query=by

Comment: Apparently yes, in 3.1: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP

Comment: hmm ... I looked in the release notes ... where do they mention this in 3.1?

Comment: ahh ... I see it shows as fixed in 3.1 .. time to run the RC

Comment: This answer explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829672/which-http-web-server-can-i-use-to-debug-ruby-code-using-rubymine-3-0-1/5034904#5034904

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recent RubyMine versions allow to specify what web server to use in the Rails Run/Debug configuration:

[image: Server choice]

Comment: Who can deny the maker of RubyMine :). Great product CrazyCoder!

Comment: it is a great product ... the first thing to make me put VIM down in years.

Comment: I realize this is stale now, but there's nothing at that link that actually explains how to use mongrel or not-webrick.

Comment: THanks CC. On windows 7 it helped me to put `gem 'mongrel', '>= 1.2.0.pre2'` in my gemfile and then run a `bundler install`. After that my Mongrel webserver ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 server
1.webric &
2.mongrel

follow  these steps to use mongrel server instead of webric...

(1) go to cmd

(2) go to application path.

(3) write down this code  "mongrel_rails start"

Comment: There's multiple different types though. Not just 2. 

Unicorn, Thin, Puma to name a few more